# How can i perform oversampling after or before the embedding?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

i came across Denny Britz implementation in tensorflow [link](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf) of yoon kim's work (Convolutional Neural Networks for Sentence Classification), i would like to perform SMOTE (oversampling) on the embedding vectors of each sentence, am not sure on how to get thies embeddings, or if i can do oversampling before the embeddings,here is Denny's embedding part :

```
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        self.W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
            name="W",trainable=True)
        self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
        self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you  want to over-sample sentence embeddings based on their classes using SMOTE. Here is the easiest way:

1- install the library imblearn `pip install imblearn`

2- you can choose  to use SMOTE oversamplig or ADASYN oversampling,

import the one that you want :

`from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE` or 
`from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN`

3- create an instance and choose you preferred parameters (depends on your problem):

`sm = SMOTE(random_state=12, ratio=1.0)`

4-provide your embedding list and their adequate label list and you will get the over-sampled results:
`oversampled_embeddings,oversamples_labeles= sm.fit_sample(embeding_list,labels_list)`

5-enjoy training and testing you network :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: and how can i extract the embeding for each sentence ?